# Limiting number of concurrent threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

What is the easiest way to make sure this code runs only 8 threads at a time. I need it to keep running and reusing threads. If one thread finishes, it should start another in its place immediately.

```
threads = []
for user in user_list:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=parse_func, args= self,user,thread_name,), name= thread_name)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: The docs for the [queue module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) contain an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up spawning the exact number of threads I needed, let's say a 100:

```
for i in range(100):
    Thread(target=get_url).start()
```

Since I wanted the threads to each keep alive and keep checking the processing queue, I used an infinite loop inside each thread, so that the 100 threads keep running. I could not use a thread pool since it would shutdown as soon as the queue was exhausted the first time - if I refilled the queue with more work an hour later, the thread pool would have already shut down at that point so I had to make sure to create a new pool etc. At this point it becomes easier to maintain my own pool.

```
def get_url():
    while True:
        item = q_worker.get()
        #do work with item
        q_worker.task_done()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [semaphores](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) and use it like this:

```
threading.BoundedSemaphore(maximumNumberOfThreads)
```

Taken from the documentation, semaphores are usually used to guard resources with limited capacity, for example, a database server.

Another example is the following, taken from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/semaphore-examples.html):
Before spawning any worker threads, your main thread would initialize the semaphore:

```
maxconnections = 5
...
pool_sema = BoundedSemaphore(value=maxconnections)
```

Once spawned, worker threads call the semaphore's acquire and release methods when they need to connect to the server:

```
pool_sema.acquire()
conn = connectdb()
... use connection ...
conn.close()
pool_sema.release()
```

Comment: Your answer looks like a a way to limit the number of threads that are runnable, but I think the OP is looking for a way to limit the number of threads that _exist_.

Comment: Ohhh, you may be right...thanks for the hint. Lets see if the OP can clear that up ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want a *thread pool*.

The idea of a thread pool, is that instead of creating new threads, your application code creates new *tasks*, and then it *submits* the tasks to the thread pool.  The pool consists of some number of threads (maybe a variable number, maybe a fixed number, depends how its implemented) and a blocking queue.

The client program puts tasks onto the blocking queue, while each of the pool threads sits in a loop, taking tasks from the queue and *performing* them.

A simplistic thread pool might have a fixed set of threads, and it might run forever.  A sophisticated thread pool might have means to spin up or shut down threads in response to changing demand and/or changing system load.

I don't have enough Python experience to know whether there is a standard thread pool interface that everybody uses or, to recommend any existing thread pool implementation.

You can always write your own.  A thread pool with eight fixed threads that run forever would not be hard to make.